# Printing a specific value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I want to output the value of `followers_count` just once. I managed to this using a `foreach` loop, however this obviously outputted the result for multiple times. Is there some other simple way I can do this?

the array is declared as follows:

```
$tweetsshow = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser);
echo $tweetsshow[0]->user->followers_count;



array(30) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (24) {
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(30) "Wed May 20 12:32:30 +0000 2015"
    ["id"]=>
    float(6.010025574446E+17)
    ["id_str"]=>
    string(18) "601002557444595712"
    ["text"]=>
    string(79) "Judge Farrugia Sacco loses appeal http://t.co/njcgvTDTej http://t.co/GRjnBt13uC"
    ["source"]=>
    string(71) "Times of Malta"
    ["truncated"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["in_reply_to_status_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_status_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_user_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_user_id_str"]=>
    NULL
    ["in_reply_to_screen_name"]=>
    NULL
    ["user"]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (39) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(390687940)
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(9) "390687940"
      ["name"]=>
      string(14) "Times of Malta"
      ["screen_name"]=>
      string(15) "TheTimesofMalta"
      ["location"]=>
      string(5) "Malta"
      ["description"]=>
      string(74) "General, sporting, and business news for Malta and the surrounding region."
      ["url"]=>
      string(22) "http://t.co/OYjxN0Y4tX"
        ["description"]=>
        object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
          ["urls"]=>
          array(0) {
          }
        }
      }
      ["protected"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["followers_count"]=>
      int(13865)
      ["friends_count"]=>
      int(13)
      ["listed_count"]=>
      int(153)
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Fri Oct 14 11:20:15 +0000 2011"
      ["favourites_count"]=>
      int(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just simply do:

```
echo $array[0]->user->followers_count; //Returns 13865
```

Comment: I had tried that initially and was given this error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array "

Comment: I doubt it can you post some more code where you tried to echo the array?

Comment: Your code has worked, was using the incorrect array by mistake.

thanks a lot!